# Express Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, http-headers

I'm new in node.js...
I would create a chat app for school project but i have some problems with node module named "express"..
Error is in res.redirect('/');

```js
    var app = express();
    var sess;

    app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));

    app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {
        var type = req.query.type;
        sess = req.session;

        if (type === "login") {
            if (sess.loggedin) {
                return res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/login.html");
            }
        }
    });

    app.post('/auth', function (req, res) {
        var type = req.query.type;
        sess = req.session;

        if (type === "login") {
            var login = req.body.login;
            var password = req.body.password;
            if (login === "" || password === "") {
                res.send('You need to fill all inputs!');
                res.end();
            } else {
                mysql query {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        res.send('Logged In');
                        sess.loggedin = true;
                        sess.username = results[0].username;
/* ERROR! --> return res.redirect('/'); <-- ERROR! */
                    } else {
                        res.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
                        res.end();
                    }
                    res.end();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

I watched youtube videos and readed forums but i didn't find the solution...
It will be nice if you can help me :)

Comment: You can't `res.redirect` after `res.send`. If you want to redirect you have to remove the `res.send('Logged In')`

Comment: only one response object should be sent per request. as @MickaelB. said, you need to use only one of the mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have already sent a response with `res.send('Logged In')`. An HTTP Request is always a single request and a single response. The snippet below is taken from your code to show what happens.

```
res.send('Logged In'); // <-- Sends a response
res.redirect('/'); // <-- Sends another response in form of redirect.
```

The `send` methods sends a string as a response, which the client will receive. So now the headers for the response are already set and cannot send another response.

And sending a message and then redirecting doesn't make a lot of sense. You wouldn't have time to read the message because you are navigating to a different page. Lose the `res.send` and see what happens.